# Change the background of all the activities in the app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to define a background as default for all the activities in the app. So I have used:

```
<style name="testStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_background_color</item>
</style>
```

and then in the manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:theme="@style/testStyle" 
    .....
```

But that way the background is applied to other elements like Dialogs title and Toasts backgrounds. How can I make that style only affect the background of the activities?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say the easiest way would be just to place it in each layout file of the activities, android:background = "@style/backgroundColor". It may be abit tedious when an app has many activities but I can't see any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:windowBackground` in your theme.